# Lower limit of a real function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> We define $f:X \to \Bbb R$ as a function, and $g: (0,1]\to \Bbb R$ defined by $$g(r) := \inf_{x\in Br(x_0)}f(x).$$
>   Denote $$
> \liminf_{x\to x_0}f(x) := \lim_{r\to 0^+}g(r) = \lim_{r\to 0^+}\inf_{x∈Br(x_0)}f(x).$$
>
> i) Show that if $x_n\to x_0$, then $\liminf\limits_{n\to \infty}f(x_n) \geq \liminf\limits_{x\to x_0} f(x)$.
>
> ii) Show that there exists a sequence $x_n$ converging to $x_0$ such that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}f(x_n) = \liminf\limits_{x\to x_0}f(x).$

I have proven that limit of $g(r)$ as $r$ approaches $0$ exists and it is monotone decreasing. But I am confused as in isn't the definition of $\liminf\limits_{x\to x_0}=\inf \liminf\limits_{n\to \infty} f(x_n)$, which would prove both i) and ii) as trivial?

Comment: My edit was for a minor typo.

Comment: Re: The last line.  We have $\lim \inf_{x\to x_0}f(x)=\inf \{\lim \inf_{n\to \infty}f(x_n): (x_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}\in S\}$ where $S$ is the set of $ all $ sequences that converge to $x_0$.  There may be some $(x_n)_{x\in \Bbb N}\in S$  such that $\lim \inf_{n\to \infty} f(x_n)$ does not converge to $\lim \inf_{x\to x_0}f(x)$. For example let $f(x)=1$ when $x\in \Bbb Q$ and $f(x)=0$ when $x\not \in \Bbb Q,$ and $x_0=0.$ Then $f(1/n)\to 1$ as $n\to \infty$ but $\lim \inf_{x\to 0}f(x)=0.$